# How to read in a csv file which has list of list columns values with certain rows having double quotes as strings

Tags: python, pandas, list

The csv file attached has 4 cols with an index field.

The fourth column is a list of list column. The records with one element are present as list [13455] and the records with multiple elements are present as 
"[13764,13455,13456]".

I want to remove the double quotes and read the last column as a list of list only. Please suggest me on how to do that.

I'm also trying to find the max value from the whole list of list.

In the sample case I'm trying to find 20930 which is the max value.[Sample file image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AhpS.png)

```
full_data1 = pd.DataFrame([]) 
   for gm_chunk1 in tqdm_notebook(pd.read_csv('CD_1000.csv',skipinitialspace = True, sep = ',', quotechar='"', usecols = ['ID','NBR','Day','CD'], chunksize=10000)):
      gm_chunk1 = gm_chunk1['CD'].apply(lambda x: x.strip('"'))
      gm_chunk1 = gm_chunk1.groupby(['ID'],as_index=False).agg(lambda x: list(x))
      full_data1 = full_data1.append(gm_chunk1)
      print(len(full_data1))
      print (50*'--')
```

The data is around 150 million records. I'm also trying to do a groupby based on the ID. The groupby seems to work fine. But I then realized that the last column became all characters and not list of list.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are currently using or anything that you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution which can be applied to the applicable column once the DataFrame has been created from the CSV:

```
# Example dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col":[[13455], "[13764,13455,13456]"]})

# Solution
def convert_str(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return eval(x)
    else:
        return x
df["col"] = df["col"].apply(lambda x:convert_str(x))
```

To get the maximum of the list of lists you can use this:

```
max(df["col"].apply(lambda l: max(l)))
```

Or an alternative just using list comprehension:

```
max([max(l) for l in df["col"]])
```

Comment: The function takes a very long time to apply on the whole dataframe after reading it in. So I applied it within the for loop, such that I convert the string chunk by chunk. But for some reason the kernel dies after the last iteration. I removed 1 column and also added gc.collect() within the for loop, assuming it must be because of memory issue. Suggest me alternatives, if I'm wrong about the memory issue

Answer (score 0):

In your case, one of the problem is `quotechar='"'` with `sep = ','`.  Without the first, the `,` in your list will be used as seperator and pandas will throw an error.  It would work great with another separator.

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import ast

dframe=u"""0|123|[1]
1|234|"[2,3,4]"
2|345|"[3,4,5]" """

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(dframe), sep='|', header=None)

# The actual solution to apply to the right column
df[2] = df[2].map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
print(df)
```

## Result

```
   0    1          2
0  0  123  [1, 2, 3]
1  1  234  [2, 3, 4]
2  2  345  [3, 4, 5]
```

The third column is actually a list that you can iterate.